# Problems with Android custom fonts using Cordova

Tags: android, css, cordova, fonts, font-face

I've built a Cordova app that is running fine on iOS.  We're now close to releasing on Android but having a problem wth displaying custom fonts.

On iOS, we use Avenir.  I've downloaded Avenir from a few different sites and the font is shifted up - displaying poorly on Android.  I believe the ascender is too small and the descender is too large.  I've also downloaded a couple other fonts and they also have this problem.

I've tried using the Apple Font Tool Suite to change the ascender and descender.  The tool (ftxdumperfuser) seems to work (I keep the sum of ascender and descender constant) but does not fix the display problem.  I've tried using ttf, svg, and woff instead of otf, doesn't help.  I've tried the baseline-shift css property, doesn't help.  I've tried a few of the tools on font squirrel, no luck.  I've contacted a few websites but they either don't respond or just refund my money.  I can muck with the css for individual elements:

```
position: relative;
bottom: -0.1em;
```

but that's a miserable solution.

Here's my font-face definition:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Avenir";
    src: url("../fonts/AvenirFS.otf") format("opentype"); 
}
```

I've seen just a little about this problem on the web with no solutions that have worked for me.  I'm surprised more people aren't having this trouble!

Thanks much,
    - Jon

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out.  The answer is to use a font editor, not Apple's apparently, such as the free online Glyphr Studio http://www.glyphrstudio.com/online/.  You can't use safari though but Chrome works fine.

I selected the font, then font settings, and changed the ascent and descent.  I added 800 to the ascent and subtracted 800 from the descent in my case.  They have a nice test drive tool.  I exported the revised font and loaded it into my Android app.  Works like a charm.

Jon